# Function call missing arguement list Error

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a project for school and have ran into this problem after doing a bit of debugging.

```
value_type main_savitch_3::Sequence::current() const
{
    if (is_item)
    {
        return data[current_index];
    }
}
```

Here I have a function that calls another function from with in that class (Sequence::current calls Sequence::is_item) is_item basically just makes sure that there is actually an item at the current index. At the line that holds "if (is_item)" I get this error

```
Error   3   error C3867: 'main_savitch_3::Sequence::is_item': function call missing argument list; use '&main_savitch_3::Sequence::is_item' to create a pointer to member   c:\users\jacob collier\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\fixed_sequence\fixed_sequence\sequence.cpp 38  1   Fixed_Sequence
```

I have basically the same thing in two other functions (is_item checking current_index) and it gives me the same error. I've looked around online and it mostly says I need to make the member function `is_item` `static`. I've tried this and it just gives me more errors. Specifically

```
    6   IntelliSense: a type qualifier is not allowed on a static member function   c:\Users\Jacob Collier\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Fixed_Sequence\Fixed_Sequence\Sequence.h   77  25  Fixed_Sequence
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `is_item` is a method taking no arguments, you should call it like this

```
 is_item();
```

If you write

```
 is_item
```

only, this is a function pointer.